# Lilke/Dislike buttons change position on smaller screens streamlit

Tags: streamlit

Hello, I made a test like/dislike option in streamlit since they do not have native support for it, but the issue is that once viewed on smaller screens the like/dislike buttons will change positon. Is there any solution for buttons to be one next to each other on all screens automatically? Tried adding col3.write(' ') in the end in case of smaller screens in hopes of separating them but did not help.

Here is the given code:

```
                col1, col2, col3, col4 = st.columns([3, 3,0.5,0.5])
                with col3:
                    with st.container():
                        st.button(":thumbsup:", on_click=save_like)
                with col4:
                    with st.container():
                        st.button(":thumbsdown:", on_click=save_dislike)
                col3.write(' ')
                col4.write(' ')
```

Comment: Design you app with small screen in mind **first**. Adjust your col spacing based on small screen.